# ion-input Validation (ng-invalid) / Control Remains ng-untouched - Have to Deselect Twice

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am applying an `Angular` reactive form to a blank `Ionic` project. My template utilizes the OOTB `ion-input` component as described in the documentation. By default, the visual indicator for an invalid user input is a red border on the bottom of this element - set through the `CSS` rules of the `ng-invalid` class:

[image]

For a reason unknown to me, I have to select and *deselect* the control **twice** to trigger the desired behavior. Why?

On the other hand it seems that the validators have recognized instantly that the value of the input is not valid. Why is this not happening for the `ion-input` and how can I get the red border on the first *deselect* in a not too hacky way?

```
export class HomePage {
  formGroup : FormGroup;
  get name() { return this.formGroup.get('name'); }

  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(30)]]
    });
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <p *ngIf="name.errors?.required && name.touched" class='text-danger'>Name field is required</p>
    <p *ngIf="name.errors?.minlength" class='text-danger'>Name must be at least 2 characters</p>
    <p *ngIf="name.errors?.maxlength" class='text-danger'>Name must be less than 30 characters</p>
</form>
```

My ionic version is: `ionic-angular 3.9.5`, unwanted behavior:

[image]

Link: [Stackblitz Example Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rvtvrt?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: Untouched controls are validated but don't display the errors. This means you can use the logic to control your form, but if the user doesn't at least touch the form, then he can not see the errors. I haven't grasped your question : do you want to see the errors at form group creation ?

Comment: My question is simply why do I have to tap the control TWICE to see the red border?

Comment: You have to enter & leave, as explained in my previous comment. If this is not the case, then please provide a [mcve] reproducing this issue.

Comment: The minimal reproducible example is already in my post. I am using ionic 3.9.5.

Comment: a [mcve] is a **reproduction** of the issue on a sandbox such as stackblitz. If you don't want to provide it, then fine, I'll answer based on your provided code : there's no issue with it. Helpful, isn't it :)

Comment: I wouldn't say oldschool, and to be honest you provided more code than 99% of the people asking a question. The main issue here is that Angular is an UI framework, and without an UI reproduction, we can't really tell you what's wrong (because as said, your code is excellent). Besides, most of the time, recreating the issue on a sandbox shows you the error you probably have made, so you simply resolve your issue yourself !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspected the input and found the issue.

This is the structure of your page, and the ionic item : [image]

The border comes from the `.item-inner` div. The selector is

```
.item-md.item-input.ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(.input-has-focus):not(.item-input-has-focus) .item-inner
```

When you click for the first time, the classes of the `<ion-item>` are

```
item item-block item-md item-input item-label-floating ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid
```

And on the second time, they are

```
item item-block item-md item-input item-label-floating ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched
```

As you can see, on the first click, the item remains `untouched`. The selector asks for a `touched` control.

Although I don't know why it happens, I can definitely tell you that it's an Ionic error. I don't know how to resolve it, except by explicitely marking it as touched through

```
 (focus)="formGroup.get('name').markAsTouched()"
```

[Here is the working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-hwe7ig?file=pages/home/home.html)

Comment: You can probably make a directive to manage this touched issue, but I think the most productive way of resolving that would be to open an issue on the Ionic repository.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your help and suggestions. Leaving this unanswered for now. Maybe someone else has some other ideas or suggestions.

Comment: No problem, but still, post an issue on their repo, you might even get an answer to that !